# Spark VideoDisplay - telling whether the video is currently playing

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, video, flex4

I'm writing a Flex video player with a "slow advance" button, and my first approach is to simply toggle between play() and pause() on a timer.  I'd like to say something like

```
if (video.isPlaying) {
    video.pause();
} else {
    video.play();
}
```

But I can't find anything like an 'isPlaying' property.  Am I barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property (Boolean) is not "isPlaying" but simply "playing" :)
FTQuest

Comment: Perfect!  Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
if (video.currentCSSState == 'playing'){
 // is playing
} else {
 // is not playing
}
```

Since currentCSSState is a protected method you'll have to extend the video component and either expose it or ad your own "isPlaying" property/method.